# How does a plugin resize it's window

Tags: c++, plugins, browser, firebreath

When I load a pdf with the following html the pdf plugin seems to resize it's windows to accommodate the complete length of the pdf file. I'm wondering how the plugin does that?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test html object tag</title>
<style type = "text/css">
    html
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .my_style
    {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="my_style">
        <object class = "my_style" data="data/test.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

As far as I understand it the size of a window that is provided to a plugin is defined in the html object tag.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Keep in mind that unless the Adobe Acrobat plug-in uses FireBreath, the answer of how the PDF plug-in resizes its window will be very different from the way *you* should use to resize *your* plug-in.

Comment: I realize that the various pdf plugins don't have to use firebreath. I just trying to understand how they do it. Ideally, I like to do same with firebreath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure speculation, since I don't have the source to said plugin, but if I were trying to solve this issue I would simply get a reference to the object tag of my plugin and set the width and height.

Haven't tested this code, but something along these lines should probably work:

```
FB::DOM::ElementPtr elem(m_host->getDOMElement());
elem->setWidth(640);
elem->setHeight(480);
```

Obviously wherever you do that you need access to the BrowerHostPtr (m_host).

Comment: I'll try this tonight on the Mediaplayer example. You think I have to issue a refresh on the browser side?

Comment: Hi Richard, good news. I have added your code in the onWindowAttached event handler and it works. No refresh necessary. This is great!

Comment: refresh would have defeated the purpose of the idea. I see you're pretty new to SO; if you want people to keep answering your questions, it would be a good idea to start upvoting helpful answers and comments and flagging answers as correct.

Comment: Richard, I would love to upvote but I don't have enough reputation points just yet. Only four more points...

Comment: That makes sense... but you should still be able to flag questions as the correct answer =]